# What is this reddish tundra ground-covering plant?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

The image is from the Scoresby region of Greenland. I am trying to get a name for the red ground cover plant. The yellow tufts might or might not be a different version of it?

[image]

Comment: My guess, it could be Vaccinium (blueberries and related plants). But other plants also turn leaves red. If you have some close-up, we can tell you better. [I do not know that flora, but I base on high alpine flora, which look similar]

Comment: There's a red species of bearberry too, that I might be. I think that's close enough of a guess really.

Comment: can you zoom in?